# Drag and drop from qx.ui.table.Table (Qooxdoo version 5.x or master)

Tags: qooxdoo

I am trying to drag from a qx.ui.table.Table widget to some other widget.
I fail to get information about the table row I am trying to drag.

I would like to drag a row (respectively its content) without it being focused or selected, e.g.g just click into the row and immediately start dragging.

Thanks,
Fritz

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm doing in this situation is to first set the tables `focusCellOnPointerMove` property to `true`.

If you don't want to have the feedback of cells being highlighted on mouse move, you could additionally call `table.highlightFocusedRow(false)` to supress that.

This way the table is "aware" of the cell/row being currently under the mouse pointer.

Then you're able to detect the current row index in the table's `dragstart` event handler:

```
 _onDragStartGetFocusedRow : function(e) {
   var index = this.getFocusedRow();
   if(qx.lang.Type.isNumber(index)) {
     // do something usefull with this information
     // and start dragging
     e.addAction("move);
     e.addType("myType");
   }
 },
```

After finishing drag and drop you could reset the focused row by calling `table.resetCellFocus()` eg. in the `dragend` handler.

This does, of course, only work with pointer devices.

Comment: Works perfectly. Note: it is necessary to e.addData("myType", rowData) in the DragStart handler as the focus information is lost on exiting the table area.